# Multiple Hidden Div Functions in HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function

For a webpage on T4, I need to use several hidden div functions. I am mainly able to edit on the post itself.

I need to be able to create multiple "Read More" functions that can be hidden and revealed with a click. Unfortunately this code only lets me show one, or the first one, if I have added multiple. I don't know how to code multiple functions in one post.

The code I'm working on is as follows:

```
<script type="mce-mce-mce-mce-mce-mce-mce-mce-mce-mce-mce-mce-mce-mce-mce-    
mce-mce-mce-mce-mce-mce-mce-mce-mce-mce-mce-text/javascript" 
language="JavaScript">// <![CDATA[
    function ShowHide(divId)
    {
        if(document.getElementById(divId).style.display == 'none')
        {
            document.getElementById(divId).style.display='block';
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById(divId).style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
// ]]></script>
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="javascript:ShowHide('HiddenDiv')">Read 
more</a></p>
<div id="HiddenDiv" class="mid" style="display: none; text-align: justify;">

<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">// <![CDATA[
function ShowHide(divId)
{
    if(document.getElementById(divId).style.display == 'none')
    {
        document.getElementById(divId).style.display='block';
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById(divId).style.display = 'none';
    }
}
// ]]></script>
</p>
```

I'll appreciate any suggestions you can give me! I'm still fairly a novice at using Javascript...

Comment: You haven't identified what is wrong with your existing code, or what you're trying to achieve. Please add more detail to your question.  Actually, ask a question, I'm not sure I can even really identify one in your post.

Comment: Hi Erikrunia, thanks for letting me know, I've just fixed the question.

Comment: You have two duplicate ShowHide(divId) functions. So I'd start by removing one of them. The ShowHide function you have takes a "divId" as a parameter, so you would pass it the unique name of each divId you want to show hide, based on the "readmore" link you are calling it from.

Comment: You need the function `ShowHide` only once - you can call it many times with different arguments for each of the DIVs. So make a button for each hidden DIV and in the `onclick` event handler of each button call the `ShowHide` with the `id` of the hidden DIV which corresponds to the given button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in my comment, you have multiple `ShowHide(...)` functions and don't need them as one function will handle hiding any div based on the parameter name.

Create your link and pass the appropriate div ID:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="javascript:ShowHide('HiddenDiv1')">Read 
more</a>
<div id="HiddenDiv1" class="mid" style="display: none; text-align: justify;">
    Hidden div 1 content
</div>
```

Then do it again, lather, rinse, repeat:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="javascript:ShowHide('HiddenDiv2')">Read 
more</a>
<div id="HiddenDiv2" class="mid" style="display: none; text-align: justify;">
    hidden div 2 content
</div>
```

You only need this function declared once:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
function ShowHide(divId)
{
    if(document.getElementById(divId).style.display == 'none')
    {
        document.getElementById(divId).style.display='block';
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById(divId).style.display = 'none';
    }
}
</script>
```